# Docker CMD with envsubst and tee

Tags: docker, fluentd

I currently have a Dockerfile with the following CMD line:

```
CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "envsubst < td-agent.conf | tee /etc/td-agent/td-agent.conf && td-agent"]
```

The image builds fine but when I go to run it it complains with:

```
Usage: td-agent [options]
-s, --setup [DIR=/etc/td-agent]  install sample configuration file to the directory
-c, --config PATH                config file path (default: /etc/td-agent/td-agent.conf)
    --dry-run                    Check fluentd setup is correct or not
-p, --plugin DIR                 add plugin directory
```

Basically complaining that I am not executing the command properly. What is strange is that if I start the container up (by not doing any of this substitution) then this command executes fine within the container.

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There are two forms of CMD command:

`CMD ["executable","param1","param2"]` (exec form) and

`CMD command param1 param2` (shell form)

Basically, you are using the exec form where you should use the shell form:

`CMD envsubst < td-agent.conf | tee /etc/td-agent/td-agent.conf && td-agent`

And even better:

`CMD envsubst < td-agent.conf | tee /etc/td-agent/td-agent.conf && exec td-agent`

More info: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/cmd

Comment: I tired doing this change but it still gives the same error.